# Liquibase maven - SQL Server out put to console during execution

Tags: sql-server, liquibase

My maven project uses liquibase plugin to generate a text file with all DDLs and DMLs. It is executing these database queries and scripts against SQL Server.

mvn run is showing only liquibase output(shown below) on the console but not the output of SQL statements. I'm able to capture output of the SQL statements in a log file using `sqlcmd -e` command in maven goals. How can I get the same output on my console during maven execution?

```
INFO  3:50 PM: liquibase: Successfully acquired change log lock
DEBUG  3:50 PM: LiquibaseSchemaResolver: Found namespace details class liquibase.parser.core.xml.StandardNamespaceDetails for http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.5.xsd
DEBUG  3:50 PM: LiquibaseSchemaResolver: Local path for http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.5.xsd is liquibase/parser/core/xml/dbchangelog-3.5.xsd
DEBUG 3:50 PM: LiquibaseSchemaResolver: Successfully loaded XSD from liquibase/parser/core/xml/dbchangelog-3.5.xsd
INFO 3:50 PM: liquibase: Reading from [dbo].[DATABASECHANGELOG]
INFO  3:50 PM: liquibase: Successfully released change log lock
INFO  3:50 PM: liquibase: Successfully acquired change log lock
DEBUG 3:50 PM: LiquibaseSchemaResolver: Found namespace details class liquibase.parser.core.xml.StandardNamespaceDetails for http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.5.xsd
DEBUG  3:50 PM: LiquibaseSchemaResolver: Local path for http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.5.xsd is liquibase/parser/core/xml/dbchangelog-3.5.xsd
DEBUG  3:50 PM: LiquibaseSchemaResolver: Successfully loaded XSD from liquibase/parser/core/xml/dbchangelog-3.5.xsd
INFO  3:50 PM: liquibase: Reading from [dbo].[DATABASECHANGELOG]
INFO  3:50 PM: liquibase: Successfully released change log lock
```

Comment: How are you calling liquibase from mvn ? Please provide this mvn setup.

Comment: `mvn clean resources:resources liquibase:updateSQL process-classes -q -Psqlcmd`. process-classes phase and sqlcmd profile have functionality to obtain a sql file with all sql statements to be executed or executed against database

Answer (score 0):

Specify configuration file in MVN like so (note the "configuration" section):

```
  <project>
    <build>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
          <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>x.x.x.x</version>
          <configuration>
            <propertyFileWillOverride>true</propertyFileWillOverride>
            <propertyFile>target/classes/liquibase.properties</propertyFile>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </build>
  </project>
```

In configuration file specify

```
verbose: true
```

Source: http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/maven/

Comment: I'm passing that property at mvn execution `-Dliquibase.verbose=true`

Comment: I haven't used it that way - but that should have worked to as per the docs http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/maven/maven_update.html. Maybe the -Dliquibase.verbose=true is not at the right position - I am just guessting + I don't have your full mvn command including this flag.

Answer (score 0):

My bad. I was executing it in quite mode. Running the same without `-q` produced full output. Thanks